# Url rewrite and trim url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need your precious help.

I have an url:

```
http://domain.com/v/12345
```

My ht access is set to pass 12345 to php script like:

htaccess:

```
RewriteRule  ^v/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$  /script.php?v=$1 [L]
```

script php:

```
http://domain.com/script.php?code=12345
```

and **works perfectly** but.. and there is a but, I would write my url so:

```
http://domain.com/12345/my-dog-is-very-fat
```

can you help to change my htaccess to works so? Because if I use /my-dog-is-fat or just / I get an 404 error.

I try to explain better:

I would share link with seo keywords in the url, example

```
mydomain.com/alphanumericCode/thi-is-my-dog-article
```

where alphanumericCode is get of myscript.php?V=

This is my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^view/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /view.php?v=$1
RewriteRule ^folder/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /filefolderlist.php?f=$1
RewriteRule  ^home$            /index.php [L]
RewriteRule  ^report$          /report.php [L]
RewriteRule  ^play/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$               /play.php?v=$1 [L]

###Added by anubhava
RewriteRule ^v/([\w-]+)/?$ /script.php?v=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z]+)/.+$ /script.php?v=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
##end

RewriteRule  ^privacy-policy$          /privacy.php [L]
ErrorDocument 404 404.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a new rule for the new URI scheme:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^v/([\w-]+)/?$ /script.php?v=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z]+)/.+$ /script.php?v=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: doesn't works my friend, with your code works just with the last / but if put something after I get again 404. :(  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Didn't get your comment. What URL did you enter in your browser that causes 404? Are there more rules than these 2 shown?

Comment: yes I have those rules:                                                          RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^v/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /view.php?v=$1

RewriteRule ^folder/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /filefolderlist.php?f=$1

Comment: You didn't tell which URL is causing 404?

Comment: I can't show my website here, I get 404 with this url for example : mydomain.com/codeForGet/wrongwords   if I write wrongword my script goes in 404

Comment: Your question says URL should be like this: `http://domain.com/12345/my-dog-is-very-fat` which is starting with 1 or more digits. Also I am not asking your real domain. Just replace your domain with `domain.com` and provide rest.

Comment: ok, sorry I didn't understand, I would a url so:  domain.com/Random code only letters and numbers/alphanumeric-alphanumeric-etc-etc  If i add something after the last / doesn't works

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Can you edit your question and provide samples of URLs that you want?

Comment: doesn.t works because now my script get ?v=abcde123/my-seo-words and get error, and I have some file linked to some folders, if I try to enter in the folders I'm redirect to mydomain.com/script.php :(

Comment: Looks like you are adding a rule of your own in it. Keep your htaccess exactly as shown here in my answer.

Comment: Hello anubhava, this is my htacess with your code inside:  RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^view/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /view.php?v=$1

RewriteRule ^folder/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /filefolderlist.php?f=$1

RewriteRule  ^home$            /index.php [L]

RewriteRule  ^play/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$            /play.php?v=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^v/([\w-]+)/?$ /script.php?v=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z]+)/.+$ /script.php?v=$1 [L,QSA,NC]



RewriteRule  ^contact$        /contact.php [L]
 
ErrorDocument 404 404.php

Comment: Try to read your comment and see if you can. Never post code in comment, edit your question.

Comment: Ok no issues. Now is `http://domain.com/12345/my-dog-is-very-fat` causing 404 to you? Give me exact URL that is causing 404 for you?